# Trying to do a:active to stay on untill other link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is this: I have two links hot/update. When hot is clicked it should turn red and update to be black. When update is clicked it should turn red and hot to be black.

This works on a Fiddle, but not on my website.

I was able to find various answers on SO, as this seems like a common thing to ask. I was implementing one by one, but none of them works. They seem to work fine in fiddle but not on my web.

HTML:

```
<div id="Space" >
  <ul>
    <li role="presentation" class="sort">
      <a class="link" href="/?sort=score&page=1" style="text-decoration:none;">hot</a>
    </li>    
    <li role="presentation" class="date">
      <a class="link" href="/?sort=date&page=1" style="text-decoration:none;">update</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  var links = $('a.link').click(function() {
    links.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

CSS:

```css
a.link.active { color: red; }
a, a:visited { color: black }
```

Right now, this does what `a:active` does, it won't stay red.

Comment: Did you include jQuery? Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery loaded on your site? Are you sure it's loading? Are there any errors in your browser console? (If you are going to use javascript, you have to learn how to use your browser console for debugging).

Comment: can you give your fiddle link?

Comment: When you click the link, is it just following the href and therefore reloading your page, losing all previously applied classes?

Comment: @jcubic yes I added jquery and no error in console

Comment: @cale_b yeah I added these two <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja http://jsfiddle.net/gHb9F/

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja 's solution in the comment above does what you want.

Comment: @winixxee Giving `#` tag to `href` is different to giving `?values` . The next case will reload the page with `GET variables` in url

Comment: Are you using a server-side language, such as PHP? If so, I can provide a full answer.  If not, I can still provide a full answer using javascript, but PHP would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var links =` does not do what you think it does.

You are thinking it is doing this:

`var links = $('a.link');`

But, since you're assigning it to the actual click event, it's not resulting in that selector.

You need to revise your code as follows:

```
// This is a "safer" document ready, to prevent conflicts with other $ libraries
jQuery(function($) {
  $('a.link').click(function() {
    // Remove the class from all other links
    $('a.link').removeClass('active');
    // Add the class to _just this link_
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Or, a version that preserves the `var links`:

```
// This is a "safer" document ready, to prevent conflicts with other $ libraries
jQuery(function($) {
  // Assign all links to the "links" variable
  var links = $('a.link');
  links.click(function() {
    // Remove the class from all other links
    links.removeClass('active');
    // Add the class to _just this link_
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/tqzt8f7s/1/

Comment: I was really hoping it would work, but it won't work. I put the provided solution below my content in html between <script> tags...Is there something wrong with my css?

Comment: You have to be specific - what do you mean "won't work"?

Comment: @winixxee - I've updated the answer, AND provided a fiddle.  This code is working, so if it does NOT work on your site, you MUST provide any errors that are output in your browser console.

Comment: thank you, but by not working I mean if I put the url then it doesn't work. It works fine if I set my a href = "#" but as soon as I change it to href="/?sort=score&page=1" it won't work. it just doesn't activate, stays black when it's suppose to be red

Comment: by clicking the link you're reloading the page. That's why it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify you want certain buttons to be highlighted based on whether or not the url has a certain query. Highlight sort if url contains /?sort=score&page=1 and highlight date if url contains /?sort=date&page=1.

To do this all you need to do is search for each of those strings inside of your page's (window.location.search). The code for such a thing would be.

```
const highLightWhat = (window.location.search).search('sort=score') !== -1 ? 'Highlight sort' :
    (window.location.search).search('sort=date') !== -1 ? 'Highlight date' :
    'Highlight Nothing';
```

This flag then can be used as a reference to highlight one 'a' tag or another.

I hope this helped! (:

Comment: sorry I don't completely get what you mean, please see the answer by cale_b, his answer works if a href is set to the direction works. that's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this `javaScript` once

```
$(function() {
   $('a.link').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
       $('a.link').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```